# Operation 'GetNotesByDate' of contract 'INoteService' specifies > multiple request body parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have a simple WCF service that I am trying to call from my web site. But when I call it I get the following error:

> Operation 'GetNotesByDate' of contract 'INoteService' specifies
>   multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper
>   elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper
>   elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle
>   property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Then I did as mentioned in error and add the BodyStyle attribute but nothing has changed. But error still appear and I don`t know why do this happends?

My operation cotracts looks like these:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/notes/{userId}")]
List<Note> GetAllNotes(string userId);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "notes/{userId}/{date}")]
List<Note> GetNotesByDate(String userId, String date);
```

Next two lines I use in my web client to invoke a web service:

```
ServiceReference1.NoteServiceClient client = new NoteServiceClient();
List<note> allNotes = client.GetAllNotes("3").ToList();
```

Web config in asp.net web site looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_INoteService">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:1095/NoteService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_INoteService" 
                contract="ServiceReference1.INoteService" name="WebHttpBinding_INoteService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If anyone knows why this happens I will be very glad to hear the cause of this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF webHttpBinding error with method parameters. "At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820306/wcf-webhttpbinding-error-with-method-parameters-at-most-one-body-parameter-can)

Comment: I read this post, it's very similar but advices given in this article does not works